# DateJS - this.fecha.getMonthName is not a function

Tags: javascript, datejs

Mates,
I'm trying to get a month name from a DateJS object.
If I console.log the object, I get all its functions. But if I try to use, for example getMonthName/getDayName/isBefore/isAfter/etc, y get an error message sayin that the function doesn't exist.

Any idea?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

This is my code:

```
App.Views.DaysTable = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#dtable',
template: _.template( App.Templates.DaysTable ),
templateTH: _.template( App.Templates.DaysTableTH ),

initialize: function(){
    // Defino la fecha corriente
    this.fecha = Date.today();
    // Defino los eventos de la navegacion
    var that = this;
    $('#prevWeekBtn').on('click', function(){
        that.lessWeek();
    });

    $('#nextWeekBtn').on('click', function(){
        that.plusWeek();
    });

    $('#todayBtn').on('click', function(){
        that.hoy();
    });
},

hoy: function(){
    this.fecha = Date.today();
    this.render();
},

plusWeek: function(){
    this.fecha.add(7).days();
    this.render();
},

lessWeek: function(){
    this.fecha.add(-7).days();
    this.render();
},
//between date
render: function(){

    var date = this.fecha;

    this.$el.html( this.template({ month: this.fecha.getMonthName() }) );
    var a = 1;
    while(a < 8){       
        this.$('tr#days').append( this.templateTH({dayName: date.getDayName(), dayDate: date.toString('dd')}) )
        date.addDays(1);
        a++;
    }

    this.collection.each( function(bed){
        this.fecha.add(-7).days();
        bed.set('fecha', this.fecha);
        var row = new App.Views.BookingsRow({ model: bed })
        this.$('tbody#days').append( row.render().el );
    }, this);

    this.fecha.add(-7).days();
    return this;
    // Muestro los dias en cada habitacion
}
});
```

This is the error message:
    TypeError: this.fecha.getMonthName is not a function

Comment: Share the output and an example of what isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I solved that issue.
I had to change my code.
Turns out that in the latest version of DateJS, there's no more getMonthName/getDayName. 
Now, to print a month name, you use:

```
Date.today().toString('MMMM');
```

Or a day:

```
Date.today().toString('dddd');
```

Now I get another issue, but I'll open another thread.

Thanks!